# How to get parseDouble to ignore "%" - Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the following code:

```
preferredCustomers[count]=new PreferredCustomer(fileData[1],fileData[2],Integer.parseInt(fileData[0]),Double.parseDouble(fileData[3]),(Double.parseDouble(fileData[4])));
```

which will be reading the line:

**778234 Minnie Mouse 165.50 5%**

within a text document. My problem is that when I try to compile my program I get the following error:

```
run:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5%"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at customer.Main.main(Main.java:84)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I cannot change how the text document is formatted, and the corresponding class has the following:

```
public class PreferredCustomer extends Customer {

   // Member variable discount
   double discountPercentage;

   // Default constructor
   public PreferredCustomer() {
       super();
   }

   // Parameterized overloaded constructor
   // Constructor chaining calling parent class constructor
   public PreferredCustomer(String first_name, String last_name, int guestID, double amountSpent, double discountPercentage) {
       super(first_name, last_name, guestID, amountSpent);
       //discountPercentage = discountPercentage.replace("%", "");
       this.discountPercentage = discountPercentage;
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   // Getter and setter
   public double getDiscountPercentage() {
       return discountPercentage;
   }

   public void setDiscountPercentage(double discountPercentage) {
       this.discountPercentage = discountPercentage;
   }
```

How can I re-write the code to ignore this "%" sign so it will allow the program to compile? I am running in NetBeans, Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard about [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)?

Comment: Don't use it. Use `java.text.DecimalFormat.parse()`.

Comment: Just cut the `%` off before parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code you had

```
 public PreferredCustomer(..., double discountPercentage) {
   //discountPercentage = discountPercentage.replace("%", "");
```

but by this time it was already too late as it was expecting the value to be a double

**but** when you are calling this constructor you can do a `replace` on the `String` value in `main`

e.g.

```
String strVal = fileData[4].replace("%", "");
double pc1 = Double.parseDouble(strVal);
new PreferredCustomer(fileData[1],fileData[2],Integer.parseInt(fileData[0]),
      Double.parseDouble(fileData[4]),pc1));
```